# How can I upload multiple videos with youtube api python

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to use the **YouTube API** in **Python** to **upload multiple videos**, but I keep encountering an error message stating that my **YouTube quota has been exceeded**. The first video uploads successfully, but subsequent uploads fail. I am seeking a solution to this issue so that I can upload multiple videos without any interruptions.

Here is my code

```
import os
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
from googleapiclient.http import MediaFileUpload
import time
import random
import pytz


# Set up OAuth2 credentials
creds = None
if os.path.exists('token2.json'):
    creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('api/token2.json')
if not creds or not creds.valid:
    if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
        creds.refresh(Request())
    else:
        flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file('api/youtube2.json', scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl'])
        creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
    # Save the credentials for the next run
    with open('token.json', 'w') as token_file:
        token_file.write(creds.to_json())
    with open('token.json', 'w') as token_file:
        token_file.write(creds.to_json())

# Set up YouTube API client
youtube = build('youtube', 'v3', credentials=creds)

print('Youtube Api Logged In')

with open('title.txt', 'r') as f:
    title = f.read().strip()
    
# Set your timezone
local_tz = pytz.timezone('Asia/Kolkata')

# Set the initial scheduled upload time to the current time plus 15 minutes
scheduled_time = datetime.datetime.now(local_tz) + timedelta(minutes=15)


print(f'Current time : {scheduled_time}')

videoFolder = 'videos'
titleNum = 1

for video_file in os.listdir(videoFolder):
    if video_file.endswith('.mp4'):
        # Create a new video object and set its attributes
        video_path = os.path.join(videoFolder, video_file)
        video = {
            'snippet': {
                'title': f'{title} - # {titleNum}',
                'description': '',
                'categoryId': '22',
                'tags': ['tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3'],
                'defaultLanguage': 'en'
            },
            'status': {
                'privacyStatus': 'unlisted',
                'selfDeclaredMadeForKids': False,
            }
        }

        # Upload the video to YouTube
        try:
            response = youtube.videos().insert(
                part='snippet,status',
                body=video,
                media_body=MediaFileUpload(video_path)
            ).execute()

            video_id = response['id']
            print(f'The video was uploaded with ID: {video_id}')

            # Schedule the video to be published
            publish_time = scheduled_time
            update = {'id': video_id, 'status': {'publishAt': publish_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ'), 'privacyStatus': 'private'}}
            youtube.videos().update(part='status', body=update).execute()

            print(f'Video "{video_file}" scheduled for {scheduled_time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")} IST')

        except HttpError as error:
            print(f'An HTTP error {error.resp.status} occurred: {error.content}')

        # Increment the scheduled upload time by 15 minutes for the next video
        scheduled_time += timedelta(minutes=15)
        titleNum += 1
        randInt = random.randint(4,10)
        time.sleep(randInt)
```

**Here is Image you asked Comment about my Current Quota**  - [image: Current Quota]

Your help would mean a lot to me, and I would be deeply grateful for any support you could provide. Thank you in advance for your kind assistance.

Comment: go to google could console under library search for YouTube and then manage, check what your current quota level is and let me know

Comment: Hey, bro I attached the image and info you asked for in my question please  check it out and help me @LindaLawton-DaImTo

Comment: How many calls did you make before you started getting that error?

Comment: Mostly I was able to upload 3 videos max but now it's stuck on one or 2 videos @LindaLawton-DaImTo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check the [quota cost calculator](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost) you will find that  it costs    1600 quota points to upload a video.

10000k default quota / 1600 = 6,25

which means that you can upload a max of 6 videos per day.  The quota resets at midnight west cost USA time.

If you need to upload more just request an extension.